# Is GHCI monadic bind strict?

Tags: haskell, ghci

The GHC manual states this about monadic binding in GHCI:

> Another important difference between the two types of binding is that
>   the monadic bind (p <- e) is strict (it evaluates e), whereas with the
>   let form, the expression isn’t evaluated immediately:

(from [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#using-do-notation-at-the-prompt))

But I can do this in GHCI:

```
λ: x <- return $ error ":("
λ: :sprint x
x = _
```

This seems to show that the monadic bind is not strict. What am I missing?

Comment: `x <- error ":("` and `x <- return $ error ":("` are different expressions

Comment: I was going to suggest trying `let e = return $ error ":("; p <- e; :sprint e`, but it turns out that even evaluated `IO` actions get `sprint`ed as `_`. Bummer! But try `p <- Debug.Trace.trace "yep, got evaluated" $ return $ error ":("` for evidence that the action (if not its return value) is indeed getting evaluated as promised.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that a function being strict means `f ⊥ = ⊥`.  Consider:

```
ghci> x <- return undefined
-- no error
```

This means that `return undefined >>= \x -> ...` is not ⊥, but that doesn't really say anything about the strictness of `>>=`, because of the `return`.  This, however:

```
ghci> y <- undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

is the case that the manual is referring to, and it shows that bind is strict in the left argument, because `undefined >>= (\y -> ...)` is ⊥.  Finally,

```
ghci> :set -XBangPatterns
ghci> !z <- return undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

This line shows what happens if we give it a strict function as an argument, so we know that `return undefined >>= f` is ⊥ *if `f` is strict*.  This actually follows from the monad law `return x >>= f = f x`, so `return ⊥ >>= f = f ⊥ = ⊥`

Answer (score 7):

In Haskell, we separate evaluation of *values* from execution of *computations*. `return (error "")` is a computation that succeeds returning an undefined value, the value is not evaluated when bound. `error "" :: IO a` is an undefined computation, that fails immediately.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is talking about the binding, i.e. the pattern matching process.

```
let p = e in e'
```

is equivalent to

```
case e of ~p -> e'
```

where the pattern `p` has been changed into a lazy binding `~p`. Essentially, `let` adds an implicit `~` in front of the pattern.
For instance,

```
let [x] = [] in "hello"
```

evaluates to `"hello"`, with no runtime errors.

In `do` notation, a binding

```
do p <- e ; e'
```

gets transformed to something like

```
e >>= (\w -> case w of
   p -> e'
   _ -> fail "some message")
```

where `w` is a fresh variable. Note that `p` does not get a `~` here, otherwise it would always match and the `_ -> fail ...` case would be unreachable.

This is needed to write e.g.

```
filterRight :: [Either a b] -> [a]
filterRight xs = do
   Right x <- xs
   return x
```

(which is a disguised list comprehension).